# Databinding and refactoring code

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, visual-studio-2005

I'm just curious about some coding practice behind binding data to a combobox (or other bindable object I guess).
Let's say I've created an object, and I want to add a bunch of them to a combobox.
So I create my object and give it some properties.

```
public class ObjectForList
{
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    public ObjectForList()
    {
    }
}
```

So then I make a list of them and set it as the source for my combo box

```
List<ObjectForList> myObjects= new List<ObjectForList> { ...bunch of ObjectForList objects...};

comboBox1.DataSource = myObjects;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ObjectName";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ObjectID";
```

That's how I understand it's supposed to be done at least. I see that implementation on all the explanations I've found on the net.

But having the Display and Value Members as hard coded strings of the variable names seems uneasy to me.
If someone comes along in Visual Studio years later and refactors the ObjectID property (to be "MyID" or something), then the combobox binding would break. And it would still compile, so no one would notice until loading the form with the combobox on it.
As well, you wouldn't be able to find uses of that property using 'Find References' since it's just a string.

What do people think about this? How do use this and still keep your code maintainable?

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  VS's auto-refactoring will not handle that, and if you have a lot of ComboBox's it can be a bit of a hassle.  As far as I know, there's no great way to solve this issue...

Comment: Great question, OP.  To build on Adam's comment and your post, does anyone know if Resharper can handle a case like this?

Comment: A hourly trip to the liquor store, as the conundrum is a nice question.

Comment: ReSharper will tell you of any string usages of a symbol you are renaming, and offer to change it for you. Sometimes that's very useful, as in your example here.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done without passing member type as well right ?

```
  comboBox1.ValueMember = GetPropName(() => ObjectForListObject.ObjectID);

  public static string GetPropName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propExp)
  {
     return (propExp.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Constants. In my case, I put all such hard-coded strings into a separate class like this:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public static class MyObjects
    {
        public const string DisplayMember = "ObjectName";
        public const string ValueMember = "ObjectID";
    }
}
```

Use this way:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = myObjects;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = Constants.MyObjects.DisplayMember;
comboBox1.ValueMember = Constants.MyObjects.ValueMember;
```

Now, auto refactoring of the property names will still not help. However, having a constants class does mean 2 good things:

1. If you are using the same strings in multiple places, then you only need to update it here in one place.. not many
2. Any future developers should know that you ONLY keep your hard coded strings in ONE place. So, they go to Constants, see what's there and if you've named things nicely, then anything that needs to change should be obvious to them.

Answer (score 1):

A way to get the property name whilst still being strongly typed might be to play with linq Expressions. In your example it could come out as something along the lines of:

```
Expression<Func<ObjectForList, String>> exp = o => o.ObjectName;
MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)exp.Body;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = member.Member.Name;
```

Of course you'd probably want to encapsulate that as a method so you don't have to re-write something along those lines each time.

```
class Tools
{
    public static String GetMemberName<ObjType, MemberType>(Expression<Func<ObjType, MemberType>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return member.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

So then you'd be able to use

```
List<ObjectForList> myObjects= new List<ObjectForList> { ...bunch of ObjectForList objects...};

comboBox1.DataSource = myObjects;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = Tools.GetMemberName<ObjectForList, String>(o => o.Objectname);
comboBox1.ValueMember = Tools.GetMemberName<ObjectForList, int>(o => o.ObjectID);
```

The drawback is you have to pass in both the object type and the Member type, however the compiler should catch this for you. This should be able to be handled by auto refactoring as well.